# How can i use regex in the --srcPattern flag in my groovy script?

Tags: groovy, sh, aws-cli, amazon-emr

Im trying to run this command in my groovy jenkins script:

```
STEP = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "aws emr add-steps --cluster-id ${CLUSTER_ID} --region eu-west-1 --steps Name=\"Command Runner\",Jar=\"command-runner.jar\",Args=[\"s3-dist-cp\",\"--s3Endpoint\",\"s3.amazonaws.com\",\"--src\",\"s3://${SOURCEID}-eu-west-2-dev-${SOURCE_ENV}-${BUCKET}${SOURCE_OBJECTS}\",\"--dest\",\"s3://${DEST_ID}-eu-west-2-dev-${DEST_ENV}-${BUCKET2}${DEST_PATH},\"--srcPattern\",\"${SOURCE_PATTERN}\"] | jq -r .StepIds[]").trim()
```

I passed in the var : `.*.txt` and get the resulting error:

```
/script.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

how can i get round this?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `"` at the end of this `\"s3://${DEST_ID}-eu-west-2-dev-${DEST_ENV}-${BUCKET2}${DEST_PATH},`

Comment: What a monster String :D break that up into multiple lines, then next time you'll find the error more easily.

Comment: Thanks @kenlukas, that worked!